# Como realizo este problema sobre matrices en python

Tags: python

```html
def datos_matriz ():
    print('Cuantos renglones quieres?')
    renglones=int(input())
    print('Cuantas columnas quieres?')
    columnas=int(input())
    matriz =  []
    for ren in range(renglones):
        lista=[]
        for col in range(columnas):
            print('Ingresa el dato para el renglon ',ren, 'y la columna ',col)
            dato=int(input())
            lista.append(dato)
        matriz.append(lista)
    return matriz

def mostrar_matriz(matriz):
    renglones=len(matriz)
    columnas=(len(matriz[0]))
    for ren in range(renglones):
        for col in range(columnas):
            print(matriz[ren][col], end =' ')
        print()
        
        
            
def main():
    mat=datos_matriz()
    mostrar_matriz(mat)
```

Escribir una funcion que reciba como parametro una matriz, dada por el usuario en la funcion main(), y que devuelva la suma de todos los elementos de la matriz

Tengo este codigo para tomar una matriz según los datos del usuario y mostrar la matriz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seria ideal que colocara la imagen en código

Comment: Ya lo coloqué como código

Comment: Hay varios problemas que resolver en la pregunta. La norma es que publiques un sólo problema a la vez. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y selecciona uno de los problemas.

Comment: Una disculpa, no sabía que era un problema a la vez, ya lo corregí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función de sumar toda la matriz la tienes practicamente hecha, y es que es muy parecida a `mostrar_matriz(matriz)`, pero en vez de imprimir cada elemento, lo vas acumulando en una variable suma y la retornas al final.

Lo anterior resolvería tu problema, sin embargo vi en los edits que también requieres la suma de `x` fila y `y` columna, en ese caso, se puede construir esas 2 funciones y usar cualquiera para sumar toda la matriz.

```py
def sumar_fila(matriz, fila):
    suma = 0
    for elem in matriz[fila]:
        suma += elem
    return suma
    
def sumar_col(matriz, col):
    suma = 0
    for sublista in matriz:
        for i in range(len(sublista)):
            if i == col:
                suma += sublista[i]
    return suma
    
def sumar_matriz(matriz):
    suma = 0
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        suma += sumar_fila(matriz, i)
    return suma
```

Y la función principal quedaría:

```py
def main():
    mat=datos_matriz()
    mostrar_matriz(mat)
    fila = int(input("Que fila quieres sumar?: "))
    print(sumar_fila(mat, fila))
    col  = int(input("Que columna quieres sumar: "))
    print(sumar_col(mat, col))
    print("La suma de toda la matriz es: ")
    print(sumar_matriz(mat))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, funciona perfectamente y con el código pude comprender como hacerlo.